# Netty 4.0 sends string message which is longer than 16 KB?

Tags: java, string, server, client, netty

I've a simple client server using Netty 4.0 in Java. The problem is I don't know why Netty Server cannot see the message sent from Netty client which is longer than 16KB. I tried with shorter message and Server can read it.

The code for Netty client

```
 class ClientCommunicator {
        public void sendMessage() {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
            bootstrap.group(group)
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(
                        new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO),
                        new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()),
                        new StringEncoder(),
                        new StringDecoder(),
                        new ClientCommunicatorHandler(message));
                }
            });

            // Start the connection attempt.
            log.info("##### SENDING TO HOST: " + this.host + " and POST " + this.port);
            bootstrap.connect(this.host, this.port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
            log.debug("##### Message sent successfully. (!)");

        }
    }

class ClientCommunicatorHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    private final Message inboxMessage;

    ClientCommunicatorHandler(@NotNull Message message) {
        this.inboxMessage = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        String message = RasFedStatusMessageHandler.RASFED_IDENTIFIER +
                         this.inboxMessage.toSerializedString().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "") + "\n";
        log.debug("#### Sending message: {}", message.substring(0, 200));
        ctx.writeAndFlush(message);
        ctx.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        log.error("Error caught in client communication service: ", cause);
        ctx.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        log.info("#### What I'm doing here?");
    }
}
```

The code for Netty Server to receive message from client

```
public class ServerCommunicator {

    private final int port;

    public ServerCommunicator(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run(final LocalNode localNode, final InpeerNodeRegistry inpeerNodeRegistry, final OutpeerNodeRegistry outpeerNodeRegistry) throws Exception {
        // Configure the server.
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(
                                    new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE),
                                    new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()),
                                    new NettyObjectEncode(),
                                    new StringDecoder(),
                                    new ServerCommunicatorHandler(localNode, inpeerNodeRegistry, outpeerNodeRegistry));
                        }
                    });

            // Start the server.
            ChannelFuture channelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(port).sync();

            // Wait until the server socket is closed.
            channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            // Shut down all event loops to terminate all threads.
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}

class NettyObjectEncode extends MessageToByteEncoder<ByteArrayResponse> {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyObjectEncode.class);

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext chc, ByteArrayResponse byteArrayResponse, ByteBuf bb) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = byteArrayResponse.getDatas();
        String data = new String(bytes);
        if (data.contains("bigdata")) {
            log.info("#### Received Message: " + data);
        }
        bb.writeBytes(bytes);
    }
}




// Server handlers
    class ServerCommunicatorHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String message) throws Exception {
            InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
            MessageContainer messageContainer = new MessageContainer(message, address);
            log.debug("\n");

            // Handle received message and write result back to the sender
            Object response = this.handleMessage(messageContainer);
            if (response instanceof String) {
                ctx.channel().pipeline().remove(NettyObjectEncode.class);
                ctx.channel().pipeline().addFirst(new StringEncoder());
            }

            if (response != null) {
                ctx.write(response);
                ctx.flush();
            }
            ctx.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
            log.error("Error caught in server communication service: ", cause);
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
```